# deleting dictionaries with negative values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a function (makeDict) which creates a dictionaries in this form:

```
def makeDict(gcRange, min_val):
     maxC = gcRange[1]-min_val
     probC = random.choice(np.arange(min_val, maxC, 2))
     gc = [gcRange[0]-probC, gcRange[1]-probC]
     probG = random.choice(np.arange(gc[0], gc[1], 2))
     at = 100 - probC - probG
     probA = at/2
     probT = at/2
     return({"A":probA, "T":probT, "G":probG, "C":probC})

Output from the function
{'A': 30.0, 'T': 30.0, 'G': -4, 'C': 44}
{'A': 25.0, 'T': 25.0, 'G': 25, 'C': 25}
{'A': 29.0, 'T': 20.0, 'G': 31, 'C': 40}
.....
```

I would like to apply the function and delete all the dictionaries where a key has a negative value

```
Final Output:
{'A': 28.0, 'T': 29.0, 'G': 20, 'C': 49}
{'A': 29.0, 'T': 30.0, 'G': 20, 'C': 50}
```

I want a loop that generates 10 dictionary while excluding dictionary with negative values

```
d=[]
for i in range(0, 10):
     new= ""
     while True:
          new=makeDict([40,60],10)
          for v in new:
               if new[v] < 0:
                    del new
                    break
     d.append(new)
```

however, the loop seems stuck and in pycharm I get "the code is unreachable"
any advice?

Comment: Your `break` breaks you out of the `for` loop, but not the infinite `while` loop

Comment: It would be easier to help if we could see the `makeDict` function itself. One big issue I'm seeing is that when using `for v in new`, `v` gets assigned to the items of `new`. You don't have to then use `new[v]` to get those items. You should use something more like `for v in new: if v < 0: ...`.

Comment: I added the function

Comment: yes, I was using if v < 0: but the I get this error : "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are committing a logical error. Your code to detect the dics with negative values is correct, but it can only get out of the while loop **if and only if** the dic generated contains a negative value. As soon as a dic with no negative values gets created, the program is stuck.

You should refactor your code the following way:

```
d=[]
for i in range(0, 10):
    check = 0
    new=makeDict([40,60],10)

    for v in new:
        if new[v] < 0:
            check = 1
            break
            
    if check == 0: d.append(new)
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: for i in range(0, 10):
     new= ""
     while True:
          new=makeDict([40,60],10)
          for v in new:
               if new[v] < 0:
                    del new
               break
          break
     d.append(new)
print(d)

Comment: If I add two breaks seems working as well

Comment: but it did not solve the issue, so probably your approach is the correct one, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- avoid assigning values of inadequate types like `new= ""`
- avoid `while True` loops
- I guess you wanted to iterate through the dictionary's values - `for v in new.values():` - more info [here](https://realpython.com/iterate-through-dictionary-python/#iterating-through-values)

I had to make some assumptions like 10 means the number of dictionaries, but I guess the code you want look something like this:

```
d = []
for i in range(10):
    new = makeDict([40, 60], 10)
    skip = False
    for v in new.values():
        if v < 0:
            skip = True
            break
    if skip:
        continue
    d.append(new)
```